# Java to MS Access Best practices

Tags: java, ms-access

What is the *de facto standard* method of getting a Java program (let's say its a Swing application) to communicate with a MS Access database?

Is this something the JDBC can handle? Apache POI?

Any others?

Need to be able to execute queries from the Java code and obtain the result sets (if applicable) for further processing.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a choice in the matter, consider _not_ using Access but a light weight db like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) which work on any OS, not just Windows.

Comment: The best practice is: don't do it.

Comment: Yes right. Don't use Java !-)

Answer (score 3):

You can either use JDBC-ODBC bridge or find and purchase a third party JDBC driver for MS Access.

Comment: What's the difference between a "driver" and a "bridge"?

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, when I tried using the JDBC-ODBC bridge to talk to Access it was horribly broken.  There were third party drivers available that did a much better job.  I just checked, and [DataDirect](http://www.datadirect.com/products/jdbc/index.html) (formerly Intersolv, formerly Merant I believe) doesn't list Access.

Today, I would start with the [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) library.  Straight-forward, docs look good.